# Fetching data from a MySQL table using a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In the [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php) on accessing MySQL tables in PHP, they gave the code to list all values as:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I understand how the while loop returns true when there is a row to print out and false when there are no more, but I don't understand why it doesn't work if I write:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while($row){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

It just returns the first row, I assume this means it is always returning the value as true but I don't understand why.

Comment: You should abandon that tutorial and learn [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942) and [this](http://php.net/mysql-connect).

Comment: Did you forget the semicolon in line 4 of your second code, also when you tested?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() only returns one record at a time. Every call to the function returns the next row in the resultset.

Comment: @vascowhite Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't realized it was all invalid

Comment: @zsawyer No, that was just an error in typing, I will edit

Comment: @Sebiddychef No problem, I thought I should point it out as nobody has bothered to mention it in their answers.

Comment: I think mysqli_* is the right thing mysql_query is deprecated

Comment: @CarlLindberg Which is preferred between mysqli_* and using PDO?

Comment: @Sebiddychef Go for PDO, you'll thank yourself in the future.

Comment: Agree with @Sebiddychef

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)

while($row){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

*doesn't work* because `$row` will only take one value per execution which means that the while loop will run forever.

From the [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) doc:

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

In the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` version instead, the `while`'s conditional expression will be executed at every loop, therefore moving the `mysql` internal results pointer forward (reading the next result).

Answer (score 3):

you should keep this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

because, at every loop "turn", $row gets a new value. If you set the value for $row outside the while statement, $row will reman the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **mysql_fetch_array** function in the while loop like:

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== FALSE){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

The mysql_fetch_array function returns **false** if there is no record remaining. So loop it until it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how [PHP evaluates expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) to determine TRUE or FALSE. You will see that it evaluates NULL as false. When you execute:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

the $row variable either has a value because you got another row of data or it is NULL. If it has another row then the loop processes it. Otherwise the loop ends.

By removing the assignment you are taking the first value assigned which is the first row and then the loop runs forever because $row never evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Because, in the second example, as soon as the first loop finishes, it doesn't execute mysql_fetch_array($result), whereas the first example it executes as it finishes each loop.